# Problem building parts of a database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I found problems after applying some code to different parts of my program written in Java.
These problems can be seen in several sections: deleting data from the database, updating database information and search, but the search was added later, and I think the problem is the code of the update section or the display of data.
Other sections work like adding to the database

```
public void showTableData(){
  try
{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      String database="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tigernew?user=root";
      Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection(database);
      Statement state=connect.createStatement();
      String query="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 1";
      ResultSet result=state.executeQuery(query);
      DefaultTableModel dm=(DefaultTableModel) tbl_show.getModel();
      int rowCount=dm.getRowCount();
      for(int i=rowCount -1;i>=0;i--){
     dm.removeRow(i);
    }
      while(result.next()){
     int id=result.getInt(1);
     String name=result.getString(2);
     String family=result.getString(3);
     String email=result.getString(4);
     String site=result.getString(5);
     Object[] content ={id,name,family,email,site} ;
     DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) tbl_show.getModel();
     model.addRow(content);
  }
    state.close();
    connect.close();
  }
   catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

```
private void btn_data_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
      try
        {
          int id=Integer.parseInt(rowId);
           Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          String database="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tigernew?user=root";
          Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection(database);
          Statement state=connect.createStatement();
          String query="UPDATE `user` SET `name`='[%s]',`family`='[%s]',`email`='[%s]',`site`='[%s]' WHERE 1";
          query=String.format(query,txt_name_update.getText(),txt_family_update.getText(),txt_email_update.getText(),txt_site_update.getText(),id);
          state.execute(query);
          state.close();
          connect.close();
          txt_name_update.setText("");
          txt_family_update.setText("");
          txt_email_update.setText("");
          txt_site_update.setText("");
          showTableData();
        } 
         catch (Exception e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }              
    }                 

                          

 private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       try
    {
          String param=cmb_param_srch.getSelectedItem().toString();
          String data=txt_data_srch.getText();
          Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          String database="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tigernew?user=root";
          Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection(database);
          Statement state=connect.createStatement();
          String query="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE %s='%s'";
          query=String.format(query,param,data);
          ResultSet result=state.executeQuery(query);
          DefaultTableModel dm=(DefaultTableModel) tbl_show.getModel();
          int rowCount=dm.getRowCount();
          for(int i=rowCount -1;i>=0;i--){
         dm.removeRow(i);
        }
          while(result.next()){
         int id=result.getInt(1);
         String name=result.getString(2);
         String family=result.getString(3);
         String email=result.getString(4);
         String site=result.getString(5);
         Object[] content ={id,name,family,email,site} ;
         DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) tbl_show.getModel();
         model.addRow(content);
}
state.close();
connect.close();
    }
       catch (Exception e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               

 private void btn_deleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try
        {
           int id=Integer.parseInt(rowId);
           Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          String database="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tigernew?user=root";
          Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection(database);
          Statement state=connect.createStatement();
          String query="DELETE FROM `user` WHERE id=%s";
          query=String.format(query,id);
          state.execute(query);
          state.close();
          connect.close();
          txt_id_delete.setText("");
        } 
         catch (Exception e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

I was able to fix the list display feature in the table, but the delete and update feature does not work. This error is related to the delete section:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at mySQL.Main.btn_deleteActionPerformed(Main.java:630)
    at mySQL.Main.access$1200(Main.java:15)
    at mySQL.Main$14.actionPerformed(Main.java:398)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 >= 5
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at mySQL.Main.tbl_showMouseClicked(Main.java:713)
    at mySQL.Main.access$900(Main.java:15)
    at mySQL.Main$11.mouseClicked(Main.java:336)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[s]"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at mySQL.Main.btn_data_updateActionPerformed(Main.java:683)
    at mySQL.Main.access$700(Main.java:15)
    at mySQL.Main$8.actionPerformed(Main.java:236)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[s]"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at mySQL.Main.btn_deleteActionPerformed(Main.java:630)
    at mySQL.Main.access$1200(Main.java:15)
    at mySQL.Main$14.actionPerformed(Main.java:398)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 37 seconds)
```

Thank you for your help